# Validate PL/SQL without permanent changes in database

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle19c

Is it possible to validate a PL/SQL code without permanent changes.
I know one can `commit` and then `rollback`, but I'm looking if there's another solution.

If I write a procedure and I want to know it will compile correctly for example.

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer and didn't see any option to do this.

Comment: No.  Copy the procedure to a different name, ie "test" to "test2" and compile test2, then drop it.  commit and rollback are for DML statements, not pl/sql compilation, and have no impact on that.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want the procedure in this case to be created?  I'm hard-pressed to think of a reason that I'd be developing a procedure but only want to see if it will compile rather than actually creating it.  The only reason I could think of would be if I was doing something like writing code in prod rather than in a development environment.  In theory, you could convert the procedure to an anonymous block and do a `dbms_sql.parse` on it to see if it parses.  I just struggle to see why you'd want to do that.

Comment: @JustinCave maybe he's developing on a production environment ;) ?

Comment: @KoenLostrie - In which case it's a classic XY problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: ***No!** You cannot rollback a compile*. Moreover, the compile itself acts like a DDL statement. It commits, even if the compile has errors. See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bb185790ce1d2a71cabe08ef891819ce).  Your best option is maintaining your version control and backup. After your testing completes you can restore your data and recover you procedures if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile your procedure and check if it's valid (doesn't return compilation error).
But in this case Oracle does just *Syntactic* and *Semantic* analysis.

- Syntactic analysis – Oracle verifies that keywords, object names, operators, delimiters, and so on are placed correctly in your SQL statement. So such queries like `select * foRm dual` will fail during this validation. For example, we can get here such errors like:

  - ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
  - ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
  - ORA-00924: missing BY keyword
  - ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
    …
- Semantic analysis – it verifies that references to host variables and database objects are valid(including their grants) and that host-variable datatypes are correct. For example, `select * from nonexisting_table` will fail this validation.

Ie, you will not get errors like `ORA-00979 not a group by expression` on these steps, since Oracle them later, during optimization phase.

More about this:
http://orasql.org/2017/05/01/sql-validation-during-plsql-compilation/

Answer (score 0):

A different answer is to try the editions feature which has been around for awhile now